# Something is fishy in this way of solving this equation in $\mathbb{C}$.

Tags: complex-numbers, roots, rotations

While solving the equation
\begin{equation}
x^2 + a = 0
\end{equation}
in $\mathbb{C}$, where $a$ is a complex number, i wanted to explicitate the geometrical intuition behind this and overthought the whole thing as follows.

Let $z_1$ and $z_2$ be the solutions to the equation: we know that $z_1+z_2 = 0$ and $z_1z_2 = a$. So $z_1$ and $z_2$ are opposite points wrt the origin, and it has to be possible to get to them by rotating and scaling the points $(1,0)$ and $(-1,0)$, i.e. we can surely find a **real** number $\lambda$ and a rotation matrix $R_\theta$ such that
\begin{equation}
\lambda R_\theta\cdot\left(\begin{matrix}1\\0\end{matrix}\right)
 = z_1\qquad\text{and}\qquad \lambda R_\theta\cdot\left(\begin{matrix}-1\\0\end{matrix}\right)
 = z_2
\end{equation}
All seems nice and tame until I multiply the two equations:
\begin{equation}
\lambda
\left(
    \begin{matrix}
    \cos\theta & -\sin\theta\\
    \sin\theta & \cos\theta
    \end{matrix}
\right)
\left(\begin{matrix}1\\0\end{matrix}\right)
\cdot
\lambda 
\left(
    \begin{matrix}
    \cos\theta & -\sin\theta\\
    \sin\theta & \cos\theta
    \end{matrix}
\right)
\left(\begin{matrix}-1\\0\end{matrix}\right)
= z_1z_2 = a
\end{equation}
because I get
\begin{equation}
\lambda
\left(
    \begin{matrix}
    \cos\theta\\
    \sin\theta
    \end{matrix}
\right)
\cdot
\lambda 
\left(
    \begin{matrix}
    -\cos\theta\\
    -\sin\theta
    \end{matrix}
\right)
= -\lambda^2(\cos^2\theta+\sin^2\theta)=-\lambda^2=a
\end{equation}
which of course is true, but this equation tells us that $a$ is a negative real. It seems to me that this calculation hides the angle information in $\lambda$: indeed, if we allow $\lambda$ to be complex then of course we get the two solutions simply by solving $\lambda^2 = -a$.

At which step did the information on the angle get erased?
If I want to keep $\lambda$ real as a scaling factor, how can I retrieve the information on $\theta$?

Comment: Can you please elaborate on the steps you used to convert the above matrix equation into $-\lambda^2=a$? For one thing, how are you multiplying two $2\times 1$ columns with each other?

Comment: I see where I messed up. I am ashamed of myself, but will nonetheless edit the question and write out the horrible mistake for the benefit of the posterity

Comment: @StinkingBishop LHS is a dot product (Not saying that is correct or incorrect)

Comment: This issue is that, thinking of both $z_i$ as a column vectors consisting of real and imaginary parts, the complex multiplication $z_1 z_2$ is \textit{not} the same as the dot product $z_1\cdot z_2$.